# Can I nest a group-by within summarize in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Without using a join or merge I would like to add a `mean(metric)` column to this table, which averages the `metric` by `sector`

```
  symbol       sector      date_bom     recommendation   metric
   A       Strip Center    20XX-08-01     BUY             0.01
   B       Office Center   20XX-09-01     BUY             0.02
   C       Strip Center    20XX-07-01     SELL           -0.01
```

I've tried a couple things in `dplyr`  but it seems like I want/need a group-by within the summarise clause, and that is not allowed.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(sector) %>% mutate(Mean = mean(metric))` or with `base R`, `df1$Mean <- with(df1, ave(metric, sector))`

Comment: mutate for the win. Thanks. If you post as answer, I'll checkmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are going to create a column, use the `mutate` instead of `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(sector) %>%
   mutate(Mean = mean(metric))
```

Though, it is possible to create a `list` column in `summarise` and then `unnest`, but that is not needed here.  It is useful in situations, where the output column `length` is not 1 or not the same the number of rows of each group.  Besides, `summarise` will only get you the grouping column and the summarised column leaving behind all other columns

---

In `base R`, we use `ave` for this kind of operations

```
df1$Mean <- with(df1, ave(metric, sector))
```

Note that there is a `FUN` argument for `ave`, but by default it gets the `mean`.  So, here it is not needed